# Is there a way to share attributes in test kitchen suites?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

Is there a way we can share attributes between test kitchen suites

for eg:

Current setup

```
suite1:
  att1: "foo"

suite2:
  attr1: "foo"
```

New Setup

```
suites:
  attr1: "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

quoting [kitchen documenation](https://kitchen.ci/docs/reference/configuration/):

> Each YAML file can contain ERB fragments, which you could use for selecting drivers, etc. based on which platform you’re currently running, or based off environment variables.

that implies that you can leverage ruby and set the values in a centralize place, then assign the values as you please.

for example:

```
# kitchen.yaml
<% my_attribute = "foo" %>

suite1:
  att1: <%= my_attribute %>

suite2:
  attr1: <%= my_attribute %>
```